# How to change any date format to specific format

Tags: c#

I am using below code to convert date format to 'dd/MM/yyyy'. It works fine on my machine. But when i run exe on different PC its not converting to my desire format. It pick the format set on that PC. Can anyone help me? Thanks in Advance.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: No, it isn't. But note that you aren't saving the `ToString()` anywhere. `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` format is the same anywhere and anytime.

Comment: Use your own culture settings. You can change them in `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat`

Comment: `It pick the format set on that PC.` <= Can you please produce an [mcve]? Include the culture on the PC where you execute the above code, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: something like this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bl6aCt)

Comment: `DateTime`s, in and of themselves, don't *have* a format. Internally, they're just a count of 100-nanosecond intervals since 01/01/0001.

Comment: thanks every one. I fix it. Exe was not updated on other that's i was facing that problem.